# World legacy Key Ruling

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have my board completely filled with mekk-knights and world legacy key is face-up on the field. My opponent activates fiendish chain on one of my mekk-knights. Does the effect of fiendish chain resolve? I thought it wouldn't but my duel simulator let it resolve.

Comment: I'll post an actual, complete answer when I can get to the text sources I want to reference, but the reason is because there is a distinction between activating a Trap Card versus activating a Trap Effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning, "World Legacy Key"'s effect stated:

> Negate any opponent's Trap effect that activates in the same column as a "Mekk-Knight" monster you control.

Assuming this Continuous effect already took place, your opponent activates "Fiendish Chain" with this activation condition:

> Activate this card by targeting 1 Effect Monster on the field; ...

Which will now be explained by this article: [Activate](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Activate)

1. A card or effect can only be activated if that card or effect meets its activation conditions.
2. The activation cost for a card or effect must be paid in order to activate a card or effect.
3. It is not possible to activate a card or effect if the effect would fail to do anything when it resolved.
4. It is not possible to activate a card or effect if it has no valid target.

Number 3 does NOT actually stop "Fiendish Chain". It means fail to do anything by the game mechanic or does not change any game state if it resolved, not negated by card effects (for example, activating "Raigeki" or "Dark Hole" when there are no monsters in the field). It is perfectly fine to activate cards as long as the activation condition is met, regardless if it would be negated by even Continuous effects.

Additionally, ["Fiendish Chain" continuously targets the targeted monster](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Fiendish_Chain), therefore as soon as "World Legacy Key" is no longer active, "Fiendish Chain" will automatically negate the targeted monster at the time of activation.

<strike>Therefore, "Fiendish Chain" can be activated, but its effects are negated as long as "World Legacy Key" is active. "Fiendish Chain" will remain on the field.</strike>

According to Shinji's explanation below, "Fiendish Chain"'s Continuous Effect still negates according to [this ruling](https://yugioh-wiki.net/index.php?%A1%D4%C0%B1%B0%E4%CA%AA%A4%D8%BB%EA%A4%EB%B8%B0%A1%D5) about "Skill Drain", so yeah, my bad. Kudos to him for finding the ruling in Japanese. Sometimes Konami make everything more convoluted than it should be.

Comment: No, "Fiendish Chain's" effect will be negated when "Fiendish Chain's" activation of the card resolves, but after that it will continue to apply its effects. That is how continuous effects work. In other words, the effect of the "Mekk-Knight" monster will be negated after "Fiendish Chain" resolves.

Comment: See my comment on your answer @Shinji-san

Comment: Ok, I responded. There are rulings for this on "Altergeist Protocol"(indirect) and "World Legacy Key"(direct) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that because "Fiendish Chain" is a continuous card, it will continuously attempt to apply its effect. Furthermore, "World Legacy Key" can only negate *activated* effects. An activated effect is an effect which has been activated(in other words, the effect resolves, i.e. it reserves a chain link). In this case, you only negate the *instance* of that activated effect. In other words, the effect which was activated, right before it resolves it will be negated by the negating effect. So model wise it looks like this:

### Building Chain

Chain Link 1: "Fiendish Chain"

### Resolving Chain

---> Begin resolving chain
---> Begin resolving "Fiendish Chain" (intercepted by "World Legacy Key" ), which negates the activated effect of "Fiendish Chain". The activated effect of "Fiendish Chain" is to negate the effects of 'that' face-up monster while it is on the field.

-->[ empty  resolution, resolve without effect ]

--> End resolution of "Fiendish Chain"

--> End resolving the chain / "Fiendish Chain" reapplies and continues to negate the effects of the targeted monster. (Continuous cards will always try to apply their effects, even if negated). A negated effect doesn't mean the effect is non-existent. It is there and will apply their effects once the restrictions have been lifted.

Your question seems as though "World Legacy Key" was face-up for the entire time that "Fiendish Chain" was, and even in that case it doesn't matter. The activated effect should be thought of as an instance of activating, so you are only negating the effect when it resolves. With something like "Altergeist Kunquery", if you negate its activated effect, it will not continue to negate the effects of the monster. You can say it continuously targets the monster, but that doesn't mean it will continuously try to apply its effects, that is because it doesn't have a *continuous* effect', so the negation depends on whether the trigger effect resolved 100% proper.

Comment: The wording of "World Legacy Key" clearly stated that it negates ANY trap effects that activates in the same column of "Mekk-Knight". That includes Continuous Effect. As long as "Fiendish Chain" is activated at the same column of "Mekk-Knight", its effect will be negated.

Comment: Yes, and the activated effect of "Fiendish Chain" is when the activation of the card resolves. Not after. The only activated effect "Fiendish Chain" has is when you resolve the activation of the card, because it has no other effects it activates after you resolve the card. There is no activated effect that is a continuous effect because continuous effects do not activate, that is by definition.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/KE2vQG.jpg

Source: https://yugioh-wiki.net/index.php?%A1%D4%C0%B1%B0%E4%CA%AA%A4%D8%BB%EA%A4%EB%B8%B0%A1%D5

Translation: Q: While this card("World Legacy Key's" effect is applying, "Skill Drain" is activated in response to the activation of "Mekk-Knight Blue Sky's" effect, and your opponent activates "Skill Drain" in the same column as "Mekk-Knight Blue Sky". In this case, will the effect of "Mekk-Knight Blue Sky" be negated?

A: This card effect will negate the effect of "Skill Drain's" activation. Once resolving "Skill Drain", it will apply again[etc..]